# Can I get the audio of the XBox Wireless Controller X Series to work when connected via Bluetooth?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I have a a Wireless XBox Controller X Series connected via Bluetooth (no wireless dongle) to my Win10 PC. I can play games fine, yet I cannot see a new audio device.

Connecting the audio jacket with a headphone won't play any audio when on Bluetooth.

If I connect it via USB-C the sounds plays fine and the audio device is discovered as Headphones XBox Controller.

Is there something I can do to get sound being played through the jack? Is my device broken or is it not supposed to work via Bluetooth connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used my old Xbox Wireless Adapter, and when I connect my XBox Controller through it instead of Bluetooth, I finally get sound to play wirelessly.

Apparently, sound playback is unfortunately not supported through Bluetooth.

---

Also [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/xboxone/comments/eoz431/no_sound_via_audio_jack_of_xbox_one_wireless/fegg70b?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) I found this statement:

> When your controller is connected via Bluetooth, audio devices are not
> supported. To use a headset, connect your controller directly to your
> PC by using a USB cable or the Xbox Wireless Adapter for Windows 10,
> or connect your audio device directly to your PC.

The reddit comment [linked to this as source](https://support.xbox.com/xbox-on-windows/accessories/connect-and-troubleshoot-xbox-one-bluetooth-issues-windows-10) but I could not find that statement on there on the time of this writing.

Comment: Linux drivers also [confirms](https://github.com/atar-axis/xpadneo?tab=readme-ov-file#unavailable-features) this.